# How to get the text from the p tag of td of tr of table in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get td values of td, but unfortunately it's not working, may be there is something wrong

My html looks like

```
<table align="center" id="container" class="body">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" id="content" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="header">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td  id="logos">
                    <img id="laitho" src="" > </td>
                <td valign="top" align="right" id="title"><p>test message</p></td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="visitor_id">
            <p>visitor counter</p>
            <p class="otp">842896</p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="pep_id">
            <p>test message</p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="closing">
            <p>Thank you!</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get to the value 842896  in python using selenium

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr/td[contains(.otp)]").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `find_elements_by_xpath`, which will return a list of web element in Selenium python.

Since you are looking for only one web element I'd say to use `find_element`

**With Css:**

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#content td#visitor_id p.otp").text)
```

**With xpath**

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='content']//descendant::td[@id='visitor_id']//p[@class='tp']").text)
```

A better way would be to use explicit wait:

**With Css:**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#content td#visitor_id p.otp"))).text)
```

or **With xpath**

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='content']//descendant::td[@id='visitor_id']//p[@class='tp']"))).text)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the text ***842896*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#content td#visitor_id p.otp").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='content']//td[@id='visitor_id']//p[@class='otp']").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***842896*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#content td#visitor_id p.otp"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='content']//td[@id='visitor_id']//p[@class='otp']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)